# How to write a code for link prediction precision assessment in python?

Tags: python, precision, networkx, prediction

I am doing a link prediction problem using the adamic_adar index. The dataset is a grid network(edgelist with 1000 links). I randomly selected 80% (800) of the edges from the observed dataset. I need to select the highest 200 predicted links from preds as below and also calculate the precision ratio. I dont know what to do next. How would I do..help!

```
import numpy as np
import networkx as nx


G = nx.read_edgelist('Grid.txt', create_using=nx.Graph(), nodetype=int)
preds = nx.adamic_adar_index(G);
for u, v, p in preds:
    '(%d, %d) -> %.8f' % (u, v, p)
    print(u, v, p)
```

Answer (score 1):

I assume u, v to be the vertex of the graph, and p be the precision.

```
import numpy as np
import networkx as nx
import random

G = nx.read_edgelist('Grid.txt', create_using=nx.Graph(), nodetype=int)
preds = nx.adamic_adar_index(G)
preds = random.sample(preds, int(len(preds)*0.8))
preds = sorted(preds, key=lambda x: x[2], reverse=True)[:200]
ratio = sum([t[2] for t in preds])/len(preds)
print(ratio)
```

Comment: Thank you. This should work out fine. Thank you for your help

Comment: Hi @Chris if this or any answer has solved your question please consider [accepting it](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5234/179419) by clicking the check-mark.

Answer (score 0):

```
import numpy as np
import networkx as nx
import random

G = nx.read_edgelist('Grid.txt', create_using=nx.Graph(), nodetype=int)
preds = list(nx.adamic_adar_index(G))
preds = random.sample(preds, int(len(preds)*0.8))
preds = sorted(preds, key=lambda x: x[2], reverse=True)[:200]
ratio = sum([t[2] for t in preds])/len(preds)
print(ratio)
```

Comment: Please don't post only code as an answer, but also provide an explanation of what your code does and how it solves the problem of the question. Answers with an explanation are usually more helpful and of better quality, and are more likely to attract upvotes