# Adamic_adar_index NetworkX

Tags: python, networkx

So i have txt file with data stored as follows:

> 1 2 1 1082008561
>   3 4 1 1082123439
>   5 2 1 1082381991
>   6 7 1 1082407219
>   8 7 1 1082407356
>   9 10 1 1082408003
>   9 11 1 1082408053
>   12 13 1 1082408788
>   9 14 1 1082409354
>   9 15 1 1082409424
>   9 16 1 1082409495
>   9 17 1 1082409753
>   9 14 1 1082409928

This is just a sample of data. Columns are separated by blank space.

In the first column there is node_from, second column is node_to, third column is weight (irrelevant for this task) and 4th row is timestamp.

My task is to make an evaluation of adamic_adar_index algorithm as follows:
divide the links so that 70% of them are for learning and 30% for evaluation. These 30% of links are those that appeared last by the timestamp (highest timestamp number appeared last). Data is already sorted by timestamp. Network should be treated as undirected and unweighted.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Look here for parsing the graph from text file.

https://networkx.github.io/documentation/networkx-1.9/reference/generated/networkx.readwrite.edgelist.read_edgelist.html

and this for Adamic adar algorithm.

https://networkx.github.io/documentation/networkx-1.9.1/reference/generated/networkx.algorithms.link_prediction.adamic_adar_index.html

Comment: Yes i know this but how do i put these 70% and 30% data parts in this algorithm? How do i evaluate it?

Comment: ok! your question was not so clear. I found an example here
[link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54147235/how-to-write-a-code-for-link-prediction-precision-assessment-in-python)